# I can't seem to understand how to get my animations from Blender to Unreal

Tags: animation, rigging, export, nla-editor, unreal-engine

I have modelled a chest into two meshes - the lid and the body. I have rigged it with bones and I have my animations into three separate tracks.

How can I combine them into one, or is there a way I can animate all the different bones for this in one track as I go?

This is my current rig.

[image: screenshot of my meshes with rigging next to the nla strips]

The hierarchy is the bottom bone>the three vertical bones through the body of the chest>lower arm of the swing action>upper arm of the swing action>upper three vertical bones through the lid.

The lower mesh is parented to the lower three vertical bones with proper weight painting, and the lid is the same but with the upper three.